# Store rendered layer

Tags: opengl, opentk

I'm using OpenTK (OpenGL wrapper for .NET) to draw 2D objects
Generally speaking I'm drawing two elements(which consists of smaller objects)

```
public void Draw()
{
    DrawElement1();  // Element1 changes every 300ms
    DrawElement2();  // Element2 changes every 50ms
}
```

In current implementation I must call `Draw` every 50ms in order to keep Element2 in latest state. In this situation I pointlessly refresh Element1 5 times.

So I need some way to store rendered state of Element1 in order to speed up my drawing

```
public void Draw()
{
    if(needUpdateElement1)
       DrawElement1();
    else
       DrawRenderedElement1();
    DrawElement2();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to render "Element2" to an offscreen rendertarget and refresh that every 300ms. Per frame, simply map the rendertarget as a texture and render a quad so it blends correctly with "Element1"

[Here](http://www.opentk.com/node/2605) is a nice tutorial for offscreen rendering using OpenTK.

*The key thing to remember is that if the cost of switching rendertargets outweighs the cost of rendering your element then this might even slow things down. But if "Element2" is complex/heavy enough, this technique will help a lot.*

Hope this helps!